# SSAS MDX Calculated Measure - Grand Total not updating

Tags: ssas, mdx, multidimensional-cube

Below in the snippet of Geography Hierarchy:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

PFB the calculated measure query:
[image]

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Metric - vs PY %]
AS

IIf([Geography].[Geography Hierarchy].LEVEL.ORDINAL <> 5,
sum(existing [Geography].[Geography Hierarchy].[1 Country].members
, case when isempty(([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64724],[Measures].[Metric Value]))
or isempty(([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64724],[Measures].[Prev Period Metric Value]))
or isempty(([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64150],[Measures].[Metric Value]))
then null
else
(([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64724],[Measures].[Metric Value])
/ ([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64724],[Measures].[Prev Period Metric Value])
- 1)
* ([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64150],[Measures].[Metric Value])

end
)
/
sum(existing [Geography].[Geography Hierarchy].[1 Country].members
, case when isempty(([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64724],[Measures].[Metric Value]))
or isempty(([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64724],[Measures].[Prev Period Metric Value]))
or isempty(([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64150],[Measures].[Metric Value]))
then null
else
([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64150],[Measures].[Metric Value])
end
)
, case when isempty([Measures].[Base_Metric])
or isempty(([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64724],[Measures].[Prev Period Metric Value]))
then null
else
DIVIDE([Measures].[Base_Metric]
, ([Metric Attributes].[Metric name].&[64724],[Measures].[Prev Period Metric Value]))-1
end
)